# Visual code replacing Sublime Text for SFDC development

Tags: salesforcedx

Most of the developers have used Sublime text for SFDC development. This involves creating a project, fetching all the metadata from SFDC org to our local system; we then make changes in our local system and push the changes to SFDC org.

Can we have the same kind of development workflow if we use Visual Code without going into default scratch org or devhub? We want something like 
1. Creation of project
2. Authorize an org
3. Pull out the metadata
4. Make changes and push the metadata in that org

Comment: Yes. I am working in Visual Studio Code and I am one of the developers who switched over from Sublime + Maven's mate.

Answer (score 2):

So far, the DX vscode plugin is focussed on Salesforce DX development, using DX source format and Scratch Org.

However, the plan seems to enable development workflow as we used to do it in Eclipse/MavensMate.

Have a look to [this blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/02/salesforce-extensions-vs-code.html) for more information, and to Wade Wegner's comment at the bottom, answering the same kind of question.

Note that if you really need to, you could use vs code with sandbox if you've retrieved the metadata first, and make use of sfdx force:mdapi:deploy, but that would be a little bit more painful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using Sublime Text with MavensMate Desktop for development. You can use the same plugin in VS Code. MavensMate provide same commands and functionality in VS Code. VS Code will also help in integrating a repo(like a git repo) in the editor for comparing code, repo - status etc.
There are several plugins/extensions in VS Code which help code completion, ESLint to validate Lightning JS.

After you have installed VS Code MavensMate plugin and Mavensmate Desktop reload VS Code, then hit Ctrl + P, enter MavensMate. You should see all the available actions, as in the image below.

[image: VS Code MavensMate Plugin Commands]

SF-DX is different we are not using any DX provided extension here. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As ntulsi says above you can definitely use VS Code to do org based work using MavensMate. However, MavensMate is a dead project now so there may come a time in the near future where it's not 100% reliable.

I'm currently in that situation, it's easy enough to DX projects or MavensMate projects from VS Code. That's how I'm trying to get up to speed on DX with our existing monolithic org/long existing source code repo. (It's not going great so far, seems like DX is far more suited for ISVs or new orgs at the moment).